# How do I replace only a specific range of regex matches with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

With sed, you can replace all matches by doing:

```
sed 's/match/replace/g'
```

Or you can replace only the Nth match by doing:

```
sed 's/match/replace/N'
```

And then combining those two has unspecified behavior (but will replace the >= Nth matches in Bash at least):

```
sed 's/match/replace/gN'
```

But is there any way to replace <= Nth matches or a specific range of matches (like from N<sub>1</sub> to N<sub>2</sub>)? Do I need something better like Perl to do it?

Comment: `replace the >= Nth matches` is dependent on sed implementation, [GNU sed](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/15518/pattern-flags-occurrence-replacement#t=201702090147396732356) has this documented... not sure if any regex tool supports `from N1 to N2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all >= N matches with a null byte:

`sed 's/match/\x00/gN'`

Replace all matches with your replace (AKA all < N matches from before):

`sed 's/match/replace/g'`

Replace all null bytes back to the original match:

`sed 's/\x00/match/g'`

Answer (score 0):

Assume this input file:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Now try this:

```
sed '/a/{s/$/####/;:l;s/a/x/3;:t;tt;s/#//;tl}'
```

If the line contains the match, add some string to the end of the line to serve as a counter. Start a loop and replace the first match you are interested in (the third one, in this example). Reset the conditional and cut off one item from the counter. If there was something to cut off, restart the loop, otherwise exit.